# subset data.table based on key being NOT an element of a list

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
DT = data.table(ID = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10), A = c(13, 1, 13, 11, 12))

DT
   ID  A
1:  1 13
2:  2  1
3:  4 13
4:  5 11
5: 10 12
```

The contents of column A are not important. I have a list/vector `test <- c(1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, ...)` that can be many times longer than the data.table. I want to select the rows in the data.table `DT` such that the key `ID` is not present in the vector `test`:

```
    ID  A
2:  2  1
3:  4 13
```

I think that `DT[!(ID %in% test)]` works, but wanted to take advantage of the data.table fast key-based subsetting. Note that the vector `test` could possibly not have any elements in common with the key from `DT`, which would lead to the subset returning the data.table itself, and it could be that all keys are present in `test`, returning an empty data.table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about :

```
library(data.table)
DT   <- data.table(ID = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10), A = c(13, 1, 13, 11, 12))
test <- data.table(ID = c(1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12))
setkey(test,ID)
DT[!test, on="ID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` and negate (`!`)

```
DT[!ID %in% test]
```